# Matter. js check if bodies stopped moving

Tags: javascript, web, 2d, physics, matter.js

I am using matter. js to create a 2d scene. 
I apply a force on a body in the scene,  this body hits other bodies but eventually all bodies stop moving due to friction and loss of energy.

Somehow I need to detect when all bodies in the scene have stopped moving. I am finding difficulty doing so since after going through the documentation I did not find a built in method to do the check for me.  Also I tried iterating through the bodies in the scene and checking some attributes I thought would determine if the object was moving or still, this got me nowhere.

Does anyone know of a clean way to check if all bodies in the scene are not moving anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to loop through the bodies and check the property

http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_speed

and

http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_angularSpeed

if they are close to zero? (Remember that comparing any float to exactly zero will almost never give the behavior that you expect.)

Comment: infact, at the moment I am using the speed to check if the bodies are moving. i.e. if the speed is below a certain threshold I assume that objects are not moving. Why isn't the speed a definite 0?

Comment: also why take into consideration the angular speed also?

Comment: In a very exact sense, motion only stops when the speed is zero. However, motion becomes imperceptible with speeds that are far from zero in floating point formats. Usually you do not account for the drift of continents, even if is is some millimeters per year. Small oscillations due to small air turbulence is also something that exists but is not counted at motion. A large tower might even oscillate by meters at its top under heavy winds, without being in motion by the uninstrumented eye, ...

Comment: Exactly as @LutzL is saying. Furthermore if a body in a physics engine is under a constant force (e.g. gravity) and is in constant collision (e.g. resting on the ground) its speed might still be very slightly non-zero and fluctuating, even though it's imperceptible. This is an artifact of how game physics engines are implemented, sacrificing accuracy for performance.

Comment: Is there any way to trigger an event that gets fired at this time? Or should I check for movement of all bodies in an async loop?

Comment: There is an event mechanism in Matter.js. The physics engine for example has an `beforeUpdate` hook, see https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/examples/events.js. It does not look like individual bodies have event hooks, it would have been useful to use an `afterUpdate` hook on bodies under observation to test their speeds. But maybe I did miss something, the documentation and examples are not very exhaustive on the implementation details.